# Example of Eigenvalue and Eigenvector in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $l$ be a straight line through the origin and let $P_l$ be the transformation
which projects each vector $X$ to $l$.

- a) Show that $0$ and $1$ are eigenvalues of $P_l$.
- b)  Find all the eigenvectors which correspond to each of these eigenvalues.
- c) Show that $P_l$ has no eigenvalues except for $0$ and $1$.

**I don't know what should I do for $a)$. Can you help for $a)$?**

Comment: What happens when you apply $P_l$ more than once? Choose any eigenvector and apply $P_l$ more than once... It should be clear why the eigenvalues must be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Start with (b).  Think about how $P_l$ operates on vectors parallel and perpendicular to $l$.

Comment: @Paul If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P_l$, then there exists $\overrightarrow {v}\neq\overrightarrow {0}$ such that $P_{l}\left( \overrightarrow {v}\right) =\lambda\overrightarrow {v}$. We want to show that there exists $\overrightarrow {x}\neq\overrightarrow {0}$ such that $P_{l}\left( \overrightarrow {x}\right) =0.\overrightarrow {x}=0$.

Comment: @Paul So, I have a question for my above comment that why  ''We want to show that there exists $\overrightarrow {x}\neq\overrightarrow {0}$ such that $P_{l}\left( \overrightarrow {x}\right) =0.\overrightarrow {x}=0$?'' Why $P_{l}\left( \overrightarrow {x}\right) =0.\overrightarrow {x}=0$?

Comment: @superckl Can you look my last comment(s)?

Comment: @Kahler one of the eigenvalues is zero, meaning there is some non-trivial eigenvector that gets sent to 0. Consider what a projection to the line $l$ does. What happens to vectors parallel to $l$? What happens to vectors orthogonal to $l$? Does that answer your question?